# Python BeautifulSoup - Text Between Div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on a webscraper project and can't get BeautifulSoup to give me the text between the Div.  Below is my code.  Any suggestions on how to get python to print just the "5x5" without the "Div to /Div" and without the whitespace?

```
source = requests.get('https://www.stor-it.com/self-storage/meridian-id-83646').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
unit = soup.find('div', class_="unit-size")
print (unit)
```

This script returns the following:

```
<div class="unit-size">
                                    5x5                                 </div>
```

Comment: just do `unit.text.strip()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use text to retrieve the text, then strip to remove whitespace
Try `unit.text.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

Change your print statement from `print(unit)` to `print(unit.text)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a faster css class selector

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source= '''
<div class="unit-size">
                                    5x5                                 </div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
unit = soup.select('.unit-size')
print(unit[0].text.strip())
```